# Reset Axes in Matlab

Tags: matlab, reset, axes

There is a axes named image in which I show the image when the user presses the browse button.

imshow(orgImg, 'Parent', handles.image);

Then I do image processing stuff.

There is a clear button to clear that image shown in image axes after done all the processing.
I used `cla(handles.image,'reset');` 
This clear the image from axes. But, it displays the XTick and YTick as 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5 and so on and also XColor and YColor as black.

I don't want XTick and YTick values to be displayed on axes and also color should be white. But I need to display the axes without above values. Now it shows the axes with above values.

How can I remove those properties?

Comment: I found the answer. :)         cla(handles.image,'reset');
set(handles.image,'YTick',NaN);
set(handles.image,'XTick',NaN);
set(handles.image,'XColor','white');
set(handles.image,'YColor','white');

Answer (score 3):

After you clear the image, issue this command

```
set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[],'Xcolor','w','Ycolor','w')
```

you can replace `gca` with your current handle.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution may actually be to leave out the `'reset'` argument to [CLA](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cla.html):

```
cla(handles.image);
```

This will have the effect of clearing the image object from the axes, but leaving the axes settings unchanged (i.e. the axes will still be invisible).